# Find column that has the most distinct values in ANOTHER column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, distinct

I have a table in my database called "assets" that looks like this:

```
party_no   ...misc_cols_in_between...               loc_reverse_geoloc_adr
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
013             ...data...                 367 Cleta Tunnel, South Moriahton, Palestinian Territory
666             ...data...                 NULL
185             ...data...                 Schillerstraße 50-50, 08340, Schwarzenberg/Erzgeb., Sachsen, DE
267             ...data...                 18701-18999 N County Road 2500E, Oakland, IL, 61943, US
389             ...data...                 Le Rocher-Percé, Québec, CA
666             ...data...                 94531, Antioch, CA, US
185             ...data...                 76 Willochra Rd, Salisbury Plain, South Australia, 5109, AU
```

What I need is, to find the "party_no" that has the most **distinct** values inside the "loc_reverse_geoloc_adr" column.

So, lets say party number 666 had 1,000 unique locations, from Quebec CA, to Antioch, CA, and many more and no other column had that many different location values, then my query should return party_no 666. So with that being said, if another party_no 777 had California, USA show up 2,000 times (not distinct) , party_no 666 would still be returned as #1 because I want to know which party_no is linked to the "loc_reverse_geoloc_adr" values that are the most different/distinct!

I was trying to do a GROUP BY on loc_reverse_geoloc_adr and order by, but I couldn't get it linked to a party_no and it wasn't really returning what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to run `count(*)`, on `DISTINCT()` subquery like this:

```
SELECT party_no, count(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (party_no, loc_reverse_geoloc_adr) party_no, loc_reverse_geoloc_adr 
    FROM assets
) AS a 
GROUP BY party_no 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

The inner subquery gives you the records, distinct by party_no, and loc_reverse_geoloc_adr. 1 row, per combination of `(party_no, loc_reverse_geoloc_adr)`.

Then on that subquery, you just get the count group by party_no, and get max value.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use `count(distinct)`:

```
select party_no, count(distinct loc_reverse_geoloc_adr)  as num_lrga
from assets a
group by party_no 
order by num_lrga desc
limit 1;
```

If you want to count `NULL` as a separate value, then a slight tweak:

```
select party_no,
       (count(distinct loc_reverse_geoloc_adr) +
        max( (loc_reverse_geoloc_adr is null)::int )
       )  as num_lrga
from assets a
group by party_no 
order by num_lrga desc
limit 1;
```